# How can I SUM these column fields from a complex SELECT statement together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created this long SELECT statement to gather data to gauge performance over a monthly period for specific areas for a customer.

I am at the point now where I have the three areas needed for grading performance, but I have to add them all together to designate a combined grade.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shver.png)

I have so far been unable to do so though. When I use SELECT CAST I get the below error:

```
SELECT CAST('Average Percentage Minutes Above 800ms Per Device' AS int),
'Average Percentage of Minutes of Packet Loss',
'Average Percentage of Total Down Minutes Per Device'
AS Total
FROM
(SELECT
(SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER
FROM NodesCustomProperties WHERE CUSTOMER like '%Example%')  AS 'Area',---query goes on and on
```

I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Average Percentage Minutes Above 800ms Per Device' to data type int

When I use SUM I get the error:

> "Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator" I tried to convert the selected data to INT, but this failed.

Below is the entire query, with some specific data changed for confidentiality.

========

```
(SELECT
(SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER
FROM NodesCustomProperties WHERE CUSTOMER like '%Example%')  AS 'Area',

(SELECT COUNT(*)*2/43200*100.0 AS INT

FROM Nodes n
INNER JOIN dbo.ResponseTime REP
        ON n.NodeID = REP.NodeID
INNER JOIN dbo.NodesCustomProperties NCP
ON NCP.NodeID=n.NodeID
WHERE REP.AvgResponseTime > 800
AND ncp.CUSTOMER like '%Example%'
AND REP.DateTime > DateADD(DAY,-30, Current_TimeStamp))/(SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total Area Devices' 

  FROM [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[NodesCustomProperties]
  WHERE CUSTOMER like '%Example%')

'Average Percentage Minutes Above 800ms Per Device'
,

(SELECT COUNT(*)*2/43200*100.00 AS INT

FROM ResponseTime_Detail REP
INNER JOIN NodesCustomProperties NCP on REP.NodeID=NCP.NodeID
WHERE NCP.CUSTOMER like '%Example%'
AND DATETIME >=DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
AND PercentLoss>5  AND Availability <>0) /(SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Total Area Devices' 
  FROM [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[NodesCustomProperties]
  WHERE CUSTOMER like '%Example%')
as 'Average Percentage of Minutes of Packet Loss'
,

SUM(OutageDurationInMinutes)/(SELECT COUNT(*) AS INT

  FROM [SolarWindsOrion].[dbo].[NodesCustomProperties]
  WHERE CUSTOMER like '%Example%')
/43200.00*100.00  

   as 'Average Percentage of Total Down Minutes Per Device' from

(SELECT
StartTime.EventTime AS Down_Event_time,
(SELECT TOP 1
EventTime
FROM Events AS Endtime
WHERE EndTime.EventTime >= StartTime.EventTime
AND EndTime.EventType = 5
AND EndTime.NetObjectType = 'N'
AND EndTime.NetworkNode = StartTime.NetworkNode
AND EventTime IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY EndTime.EventTime)
AS UpEventTime,
Nodes.Caption, StartTime.Message, DATEDIFF(Mi, StartTime.EventTime,(SELECT TOP 1 EventTime 
FROM Events AS Endtime
INNER JOIN NodesCustomProperties NCP on Nodes.NodeID=NCP.NodeID
WHERE EndTime.EventTime > StartTime.EventTime AND EndTime.EventType = 5 AND EndTime.NetObjectType = 'N'
AND EndTime.NetworkNode = StartTime.NetworkNode
ORDER BY EndTime.EventTime))
AS OutageDurationInMinutes 

FROM Events StartTime INNER JOIN Nodes ON StartTime.NetworkNode = Nodes.NodeID
INNER JOIN NodesCustomProperties NCP on Nodes.NodeID=NCP.NodeID

WHERE (StartTime.EventType = 1) AND NCP.CUSTOMER like '%Example%'
) as uptimetable
WHERE outageDurationInMinutes IS NOT NULL
AND UpEventTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
OR
outageDurationInMinutes IS NOT NULL 
AND UpEventTime >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use square brackets instead of single quotes when using names that don't adhere to the naming conventions for regular database identifiers.

e.g.  `[Average Percentage Minutes Above 800ms Per Device]`

Avoid using special characters, spaces, and leading numbers in database names, table names, column names, and aliases. When they do occur, wrap them in square brackets.

Reference:

- [Database Identifiers - docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers)

Comment: Thanks, adding the changes you described worked in the end. I was able to use SUM from the different columns.